# Giving EditorFor an ID Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, datepicker

I have a template for Views along with lots of JQuery that pulls input from a `EditorFor`. For this reason I'd prefer to keep using my `EditorFor` rather than use something like `<input type="text">`

I now have implemented a **datepicker** and all I need is an `ID` attribute in order for it to do its magic ( `$('#datepicker').datepicker();` ), so I am wondering is there any way to force an `id` on an EditorFor?

Here is my attempt thus far.

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate, new {@id ="datepicker" })
```

And if that "should" be working is there something else that could be causing the issue?

I use an `<input>` tag for a **modal** in this same View which uses this **datepicker** just fine so I know it works, but I simply cannot get the `EditorFor` to work with it.

Thank you!

EDIT: `@ForEach` that takes each item that add's datepicker to the releaseDate of each item. (2nd `td` down)

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>

                <td class="col-lg-2">
                    <span class="item-display">
                        <span style="font-size: 17px;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="item-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </span>

                </td>


                <td class="col-lg-3">
                    <span class="item-display">
                        <span style="font-size: 17px;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="item-field">
                       @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate, new {@id="datepicker"})
                        @*@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate, new {@id ="datepicker" })*@

                    </span>

                </td>


                <td class="col-lg-3">
                    <span class="item-display">
                        <span style="font-size: 17px; font-style:italic">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="item-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </span>
                </td>


                <td class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <span style="visibility:hidden" class="ID col-lg-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>

                    <span class="item-edit-button">
                        <button type="button" onclick="editFunction(this)" class=" btn btn-warning col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-0"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="item-save-button">
                        <button type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this)" class="btn btn-success col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Save</button>
                    </span>
                    <!-- Modal Button-->
                    <span class="item-delete-button">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.ID" onclick="deleteStart(this)">
                            <span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete
                        </button>
                    </span>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="@item.ID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #d9534f">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="font-size: 30px; font-style:oblique; color:white">Delete</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <span style="font-size: 20px">Are you sure you want to delete movie: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)?</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" onclick="deleteStopped(this)" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="button" style="margin-right:10px" onclick="deleteFunction(this)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td colspan="12">
                    <p style="font-size: 17px; font-style: italic; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif">
                        Movie ID: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                        <br />
                        Placeholder
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.EditorFor()` helper don't have overload that takes html attributes, use `Html.TextBoxFor()` helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate, new {@id ="datepicker" })
```

Here is [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) documentation for `Html.EditorFor()` and [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is for `Html.TextBoxFor()`

### NOTE:

When you write:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
```

It is rendered like this:

```
<input type="text" name="ReleaseDate" id="ReleaseDate"/>
```

so it sets the id and name attribute to Model property,so you just can use that id if you want to use `Html.EditorFor()` helper.

Comment: So it sounds like I will have to modify all my JQuery that deals with EditorFor and convert it to TextBoxFor?

Comment: no you don't need to modify jquery code, as they both render same html

Comment: ``<input type="text" name="ReleaseDate" id="ReleaseDate" />``

Comment: ah so setting/receiving is the same? like .val(), .text(). and .html()

Comment: Gotcha! Okay well I added it but nothing is happening still, what should I look at next?

Comment: what you mean nothing is happening, id is not passed?

Comment: The datepicker is not appearing. All I need to do is give it that ID and it should work, correct? Based off the listener of `$('#datepicker').datepicker();` Datepicker works for everything else with that ID being set.

Comment: can you show the complete script of it is it inside ``document.ready()``

Comment: Actually I just have it by itself in `<script>` tags. It runs fine for my modal calls so I didn't think I needed document ready code around it. So I added document ready and still nothing happens with datepicker. All my script `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Movies.js")    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myscript")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();

    });
</script>`

Comment: is there any other element with id datepicker on the page?

Comment: Oh wait, question. This is sitting in a `@foreach` in the View, meaning that this datepicker is on x amount of items, do I need to reference it anything or does that not matter?

Comment: each table row's ReleaseDateItem and there is one on my modal popup for a Create option.

Comment: then use class attribute instead of because id must be unique of all elements otherwise it will not work

Comment: Ah okay so do something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate, new {@class="datepicker"})`? I added my `@foreach` above as well