# Blur event function in IE11 and IE10

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, jquery-events

I have a textbox in my ASP.Net MVC application and I need to do some validation when the textbox loses focus, so I have used a blur event.

The below event is working fine in Chrome browser but not working in IE11 and IE10.

Script Code:

```
$("#NewFileName").on("blur", function () {
alert('triggered');
});
```

ASP.NET MVC HTML code:

```
<div class ="span6">
                <p>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileName, new { type = "file" }) 
                </p>
</div>
```

I tried with different events like "focusout" for IE, but no focus/blur event are working in IE.  What is the correct event for IE10 and 11 browsers?

Comment: works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/fyjmxs1h/

Comment: I'd check if there's any .off() assigned to this field, if you start a function AFTER element is rendered or even do you start this function at all?

Comment: @eeree nope. "off()" event not binded with that element. i am wondering about correct event name or blur itself will work in all browsers.

Comment: @SivaRajini Yes, *blur* event works perfectly fine with IE. Tested from IE7 to Edge. I'd start with checking events that are attached to your input. 99% that the problem is not an event itself, but wrong logic, that attach it.

Answer (score 4):

File input types do not support `focus` and `blur` in IE due to security restrictions:

> Windows Internet Explorer 8 form submission has been changed so that a file upload control (input type=file) only submits the file path to the server. Previously, the full path was sent to the server. Also, programmatic access to the value property of the file upload control also removes the path information from the file name.
>
> There is no workaround for this feature and it may not be turned off. Providing access to the full path of the file (for Internet and Restricted sites) is a security measure. Stripping out the full path in these instances prevents relatively uncontrolled sites from accessing information that can potentially be exploited.

`NewFileName` needs to be set as the ID attribute of the textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileName, @id = "NewFileName")
```

In addition:

> In Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 and greater, elements that expose the blur method must have the TABINDEX attribute set.

**References**

- [blur method (Internet Explorer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536347)
- [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility: Event 1056 - File Name Restriction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565634)
- [Internet Explorer 7 and blur (with input type=file) | Matthias Wessendorf's Weblog](https://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2008/02/19/internet-explorer-7-and-blur-with-input-typefile/)
- [Validate input type=file with onBlur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607354/1113772)
- [Giving EditorFor an ID Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066038/1113772)

Comment: Matthias Wessendorf's blog is gone, so that link is broken. I couldn't find your quote about the TABINDEX in any of those links. I found it on some other discontinued sites, but apparently that knowledge is disappearing from documentation sites.